# I want you to finish/to have finished

Tags: present-perfect, infinitives, sentence-choice, present-simple

I've given a friend of mine a task to do. I want him to finish it before I come in after an hour.

Which the simple or the perfect infinitive better with **before** and **by**?

> I want you to finish it **before** an hour passes.
> I want you to have finished it **befo​​​​​re** an hour passes.

> I want you to finish it **by** the time an hour passes.
> I want you to have finished it **by** the time an hour passes.

Comment: Before ain't great. within an hour is better.

Comment: They would sound a lot better if you used the present perfect: **....before / by the time an hour has passed.**

Comment: In the UK a schoolteacher or a sergeant major might say, "I _want_ you to..." but a _friend_ would generally say, "I'd _like_ you to..." [or "I was wondering if" or "hoping you could/might"] "...have it finished within an hour."

Comment: Either "within" with a period or "by/before" with a particular point in time. "I want you to finish it by 12 o'clock", or "I want you to finish it before 12 o'clock". I can't see why adding "passes" is an improvement, although you would say "I want him to have it finished before he goes home".

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine, but as many have mentioned in the comments, "within" is best used. If not you can use present perfect tense proposed by @RonaldSole:

> I want/I'd like you to finish it within an hour.

> I want/I'd like you to finish it before/by the time an hour has passed.

Usually the first sentence is clearer and easier to underatand here.